# linux raspberry OS disk full but different df and ncdu giga count

Tags: linux, disk-usage, disk

[image]

[image]

I have a raspberrypi 3b+, with 32gb sdcard.
As you can see, /dev/root is about 28GB and  df -h command says that / is full.
sudo ncdu instead shows different results.
Excluding media (that is a virtual partition containing the external mounted disks, 2 in total), the sum of /usr /var /home etc is around 7GB, not 28GB.

I read all related articles here, and the only useful is this: [ncdu and du showing different sizes than df](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/608030/ncdu-and-du-showing-different-sizes-than-df)
that says "when your disks are not mounted, the system is writing on /mnt".

I checked my /mnt, and has only 2 empty folders "/mnt/backup_hd" and "/mnt/sdcard" and these folder are empty.

I'm getting crazy trying to understand why every one ore two months I have to clean the space but no cleaning is sufficient, there is something that full up the disk but du/ncdu can't see it so I can't wipe it out.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: So as the link you mention, did you check that (see your link) "It is possible that you wrote to /mnt when your disks were not mounted." Except **that would be /media for your case**.

Comment: Please do not post text as a picture.